# Service worker fetching static assets for multilingual site

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I've got static site (generated with Pelican) with a multilingual structure, e.g.

```
www.example.com/
www.example.com/index.html
www.example.com/page1.html
www.example.com/es/
www.example.com/es/index.html
www.example.com/es/page1.html
```

I've cached the JS and CSS and the index files with a service worker install event:

```
const staticCacheName = 'static-cache-v5';

const filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/es/index.html',
  '/offline.html',
  'static/js/main..js',
  'static/css/styles.css',
]


self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );

  self.skipWaiting();
});
```

and I'm using a cache, falling back to network strategy:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
      return response || fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
});
```

The issue I have is when the `www.example.com/es/index.html` or `es/offline.html`  is accessed offline and loading the CSS and JS files. The problem is that since the es/index.html files references the CSS and JS as `../static/css/styles.css` and `../static/js/main.js`, they can't find the files in the cache. I've tried to find a way to alter the request and response but so far I've failed. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can write some logic in your code where the `caches.match(event.request)` is changed to something like `caches.match(event.request) || caches.match(*canonical-url*)` (in pseudo-code). You have possibly had a bug in your code if you tried this already. Another option would be to cache the files twice – with their root-relative paths and their canonical "../" paths. This of course isn't optimal since cache is used twice.

I think the best option would be to generate your site so that it always uses root-relative static asset paths. Replace all "../static/bla" with "/static/bla" and everything should work out of the box very neatly :)